# Monitoring flow of information through WebSphere Process Server 7

Tags: monitoring, logging, websphere

We are currently building a system using WPS.

One of the requirements is that the business wants to be able to see all the calls that have gone through WPS for a given social security number.

One way we could solve this is just by logging all calls to an external logging database.

We were wondering is there any built in functionality in WPS that would allow us both to log this information and to display it to the users?

Comment: I believe you meant Process Server 7, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The monitoring solution designed for IBM WebSphere Process Server (now known as IBM Business Process Manager) is **[IBM WebSphere Business Monitor](http://ibm.com/software/integration/business-monitor/)** (now known as **IBM Business Monitor**).

It allows you to monitor your process flows in WPS, offering automated ways of generating Monitor models from your processes designed in IBM WebSphere Integration Developer (now known as IBM Integration Designer) and IBM Process Designer. You can monitor specific process instances and Key Performance Indicators (KPIs), analyze data and also generate predictions.